# Soft Screen Keyboard Push my layout content to top

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on `Android` Application

[image]

The top content i want it to be fixed and shown always even when the soft screen keyboard appears.
The center area where the messages are inside a `ScrollView` .
When i press the `editText` to write something it pushes all the content and the header become hidden (The top green area with picture and contact name).

like this :

[image]

I tried some answers but i didn't reach the result that i want .

I tryed  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the `AndroidManifest` but it doesn't change anything.
I tried also  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` it gaves me this result.

[image]

But it didn't show the `editText` so i can see what i am typing.

This is My `XML` code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.projects.zak_dev.chatobev3.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1920dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/msg_bg_3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@color/mainGreenColor"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/rounded_image"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/contact_img" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/contact_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Online"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msgContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_message_border"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="260dp"
                android:text="Test for a long test alongside the time"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="21:19"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_received_msg_border"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="260dp"
                android:text="Test for a long test alongside the time"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="21:19"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/mainGreenColor"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type a message here ..."
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_send_btn"
        android:onClick="sendMessageEvent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I searched a lot over the the answers and blogs but i still can't find a solution, Can someone help me please .